# Is it necessary to specify the size of an array in java?

Tags: java

Is it necessary to specify the size of an array in java
Like is it necessary to every time do this

```
int arr[]=new int[n];
```

to specify the size is it necessary!
(Don't consider ArrayList please!)

Comment: Yes, it is necessary.

Comment: yes, You can't declare and initialize an array without specifying the size.look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/404/creating-and-initializing-arrays#t=201607261943570177)

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 possibilities:

specify size:

```
int[] array = new int[n];
```

specify size indirectly:

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,67,345};
```

use `ArrayList` with open size:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

If you want to have a list with a changeable size, I advise you to use `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

In a word - yes. You must specify the size of an array when you initialize it. Note that there's also a syntax to initialize an array from it's elements (e.g. `new int[]{1, 2, 3}`) which doesn't explicitly require the size, but deduces it from the number of elements you provided.